# How to make a menu define a variable

Tags: batch-file, menu

I'm a batch scripting novice. I can spin up basic menus for my own needs but I need a little nudge in the right direction regarding menus and variables.

So I wish to create a menu which defines a variable upon selection of one, from multiple items to define the path of an item where file operations begin.

So here's an example I'm looking to figure out how tot integrate:

```
CHOICE /N /C:1234 /M "Option: "
IF ERRORLEVEL ==4 SET foo
IF ERRORLEVEL ==3 SET bar
IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 SET quak
IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 SET baz

[something something define %bark% from above]

rem overwrite file.png with new option
copy %src%\%bark%\file.png %des%\%quak%\file.png
```

Now I know I am missing stuff here. *I'm an idiot* if I hadn't made that clear enough. How do I make a batch menu which sets a variable for doing the same thing, multiple times without bloating my code using unique operations for each?

Comment: Remove `==` from your code in `if errorlevel`. It should work. e.g. `IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET foo`

Comment: You can also use `%errorlevel%` instead of `errorlevel`. Either will work.

Comment: `SET foo`, `SET bar`, `SET quak` and `SET baz` will each only output a listing of variables whose name begin with `foo`, `bar`, `quak` and `baz` respectively along with their values. I think it unlikely that is what you want. Perhaps you should be more specific about your options and what you want the value of `%bark%` to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is here:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL ==N..
```

it should instead be:

```
if "%errorlevel%"=="N"
```

or

```
if errorlevel N
```

If you really want to set something, then I would say rather goto a `label` and set things there:

```
CHOICE /N /C:1234 /M "Option: "
if "%errorlevel%"=="4" goto :foo
if "%errorlevel%"=="3" goto :bar
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto :quak
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto :baz
:foo
set foo=bar
goto :eof
:bar
...
```

but personally I prefer doing things directly within `if` statement, instead of having to `goto` many labels.

```
CHOICE /N /C:1234 /M "Option: "
if "%errorlevel%"=="4" (
    set "foo=bar"
    goto :next
)
if "%errorlevel%"=="3" (
    set "foo=bar"
    goto :next
)
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" (
    set "foo=bar"
    goto :next
)
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (
    set "foo=bar"
    goto :next
)
:next
echo %foo%
```

Finally, just so we are 100% on this, a variable needs a value, so make sure you use `set "foo=bar"` else it will just echo a variable with value, only if it does exist. You can test that by running cmd.exe and do `set "foo=bar"` then do `set foo` to see the result.

Comment: @double-beep no the parenthesized block `(commands...)` after the `if` statement is a code block.

Comment: @double-beep what was the purpose of chaning your comment after I commented that you are wrong? Also, what makes you think I do not know what a code block is?

Comment: @double-beep: Why should delayed expansion be necessary here?

Comment: @stephan. I actually had the `echo` inside of the parenthesized block hence his comment. :)

Comment: @double-beep: the only `echo` command is the last line - outside of any code block. No need for delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two different ways: the first one, is to completely remove the `==` where presented, since this is the most common way to do this when using `choice` command:

```bat
choice /N /C:1234 /M "Option: "
if errorlevel 4 set foo & goto :foo
if errorlevel 3 set bar & goto :bar
if errorlevel 2 set quak & goto :quak
if errorlevel 1 set baz & goto :baz

[something something define %bark% from above]

rem overwrite file.png with new option
copy %src%\%bark%\file.png %des%\%quak%\file.png
```

The descending order is just because `if errorlevel x` means if the `errorlevel` variable is **greater** than ***or equal*** to `x`.

The second, not so common way, which is used to set variables when the condition is true, to do this is as follows (note that here we don't mind about the order):

```bat
choice /N /C:1234 /M "Option: "
if %errorlevel% EQU 4 set foo & goto :foo
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 set bar & goto :bar
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 set quak & goto :quak
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 set baz & goto :baz

[something something define %bark% from above]

rem overwrite file.png with new option
copy %src%\%bark%\file.png %des%\%quak%\file.png
```

You can replace `EQU` with `==` here, although not recommended.

Note that if you want to ***set*** variables if the condition is true, use the second way and set the variables in the format `set "var=value"`.

For example:

```bat
if %errorlevel% EQU 4 set "foo=1"
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 set "bar=2"
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 set "quak=3"
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 set "baz=4"
```

or whatever.

As not to execute all the 4 `if`s, you can add a `GoTo` here:

```bat
if %errorlevel% EQU 4 set "foo=1" & goto :foo
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 set "bar=2" & goto :bar
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 set "quak=3" & goto :quak
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 set "baz=4" & goto :baz
```

and replace the example subroutines with the actual names.

For more information about the commands used, type in `cmd.exe`:

- `if /?`
- `choice /?`
- `set /?`
- `goto /?`

Comment: Just so the OP understands, using the `errorlevel` option all 4 of the `IF` statements will execute when they are in high to low order and the user selects option 4. You may want to use a `GOTO` after the `SET` command.

Comment: `if errorlevel 4 set foo & goto :foo` ??? You are not settiing any value, it will just echo a value of `foo` if the variable existed

Comment: `set foo` that is what is wrong. When you set a variable, it needs a value. like `set foo=bar`

Comment: @double-beep No, the title very specifically says __"How to make a menu define a variable"__

Comment: Alright, alright, ALRIGHT y'all settle down. I am trying to have a menu set a variable so that variable can be used in a path, so that once the path variable is set, it can represent a specific location among a bunch of directories where within each directory contains files of the same name destined to different destinations. I already defined variables for the source directories, I want one var to represent another to change source by user choice, then return to menu so the user can do it again post-op.

Comment: Brandon then I suggest you edit you question and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

choice /n /c:1234 /m "Press a key: "

for /f "tokens=%errorlevel% delims=|" %%A in (
    "foo|bar|quak|baz"
) do set "result=%%A"

echo %result%
```

This will `set` the variable name `result` to the chosen value
of the `errorlevel` number returned by `choice`:

1. `foo`
2. `bar`
3. `quak`
4. `baz`

if `3` is pressed, then `result` is set to the value of `quak`.

The string `"foo|bar|quak|baz"` is delimited by `|` to create
4 tokens of values which will align with the sequence of `1234`
options of `choice`.

If the values are other then you can change as needed.

---

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Test 1.
call :select "1|foo" "2|bar" "3|quak" "4|bar"
echo Result: %result%

rem Test 2.
call :select "a|apple" "b|orange" "c|banana"
echo Result: %result%

rem Test 3.
call :select
echo Result: %result%

rem Test 4 repeat.
:menu
call :select "1|car" "2|boat" "3|airplane"
echo Result: %result%

call :select "1|quit" "2|restart menu"
if /i "%result%" == "quit" goto :endmenu

goto :menu
:endmenu

exit /b


:select
setlocal
set args=%*
set "choices="
set "values="

rem Set default choices and values if needed.
if "%~1" == "" set args="y|y" "n|n"

rem Display menu with choices and values.
echo(

for %%A in (%args%) do (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=|" %%B in ("%%~A") do (
        echo  %%B  %%C

        if defined choices (
            call set "choices=%%choices%%|%%B"
        ) else set "choices=%%B"

        if defined values (
            call set "values=%%values%%|%%C"
        ) else set "values=%%C"
    )
)

echo(

rem Prompt to press a key.
choice /n /c:%choices:|=% /m "Press a key: "

rem Get the value from the errorlevel.
for /f "tokens=%errorlevel% delims=|" %%A in ("%values%") do set "result=%%A"

rem Set nonlocal result.
endlocal & set "result=%result%"
exit /b
```

This uses a label named `:select`, which does the following:

- `echo` the menu choices and values.
- Prompt using `choice`.
- Sets variable name `result` to chosen value.

The arguments passed to the called label of `:select`, are
each enclosed by double quotes. If you assign `a` as the
choice key and `apple` as the result value, then you would
use the argument `"a|apple"`. The `|` delimiter separates
the key and the value.

You should not need to change the code in the label of
`:select` unless you want to improve it.

You mentioned "*same thing, multiple times, without bloating*",
so `Test 4 repeat` perhaps does what you want.
Notice the code between labels of `:menu` and `:endmenu` is
much less than if you had to repeat the menu display,
choice commands and handling the `errorlevel` to set a
value to a variable name.